# The dimension of the Zariski tangent space is bounded for a finitely generated algebra

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Can anyone suggest a published reference for the following fact:

> For a given finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field, the dimension of the Zariski tangent space at maximal ideals is bounded.

? I can't find it in the much beloved Stacks project.

Comment: It's a lower semi-continuous function on a (non-Hausdorff) compact space, isn't it?

Comment: YCor's argument works in greater generality, but in your case you can get an explicit bound. If $A = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is finitely generated over a field, the Zariski tangent space at any point of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ has dimension at most $n$. This is because the tangent space of a point of $\Spec(A)$ is canonically a subspace of the tangent space of the corresponding point in $\mathbf{A}^n$.

Comment: @YCor does your argument also work for Noetherian algebras? Can you write up the argument so that I can accept an answer?

Comment: I think Nagata's example of a Noetherian ring with infinite Krull dimension is also a counterexample to Noetherian rings having bounded Zariski tangent space dimension, since it has local rings of all dimensions as localizations.

Comment: Well I haven't checked the l.s.c. fact in the case of f.g. algebras, and Will Sawin's argument shows it fails in a too broad generality.